# Torch: Model fast when learning/testing, slow when using it

Tags: torch

I have an issue using a learned model with torch.

I followed this howto http://code.cogbits.com/wiki/doku.php?id=tutorial_supervised to train a model. Everything is fine, my model was trained and I have corrects results when I use my model. But it's slow !

The testing part for training look like this:

```
model:evaluate()

-- test over test data
print('==> testing on test set:')
for t = 1,testData:size() do
   -- disp progress
   xlua.progress(t, testData:size())

   -- get new sample
   local input = testData.data[t]
   if opt.type == 'double' then input = input:double()
   elseif opt.type == 'cuda' then input = input:cuda() end
   local target = testData.labels[t]

   -- test sample
   local pred = model:forward(input)
   confusion:add(pred, target)
end

-- timing
time = sys.clock() - time
time = time / testData:size()
print("\n==> time to test 1 sample = " .. (time*1000) .. 'ms')
```

I have the following speed recorded during testing:

`==> time to test 1 sample = 12.419194088996ms`

(Of course it vary, but it's ~12ms).

I want to use the learned model on others images, so I did this in a simple and new script:

```
(... requires)

torch.setnumthreads(8)
torch.setdefaulttensortype('torch.FloatTensor')

model = torch.load('results/model.net')
model:evaluate()

(... Image loading, resizing and normalization)

local time = sys.clock()

local result_info = model:forward(cropped_image:double())

print("==> time to test 1 frame = " .. (sys.clock() - time) * 1000 .. "ms")
```

The time spent is much bigger, I have the following output: `==> time to test 1 frame = 212.7647127424ms`

I tested with more than one image, always with the resizing and normalization outside clock's measurements, and I always have > 200ms / image.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and why my code is much slower than during the training/testing.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you use the `-type cuda` option when you launched the training? It might explain the difference, as it will run the training on the GPU, while your custom test script runs on the CPU.

Comment: No, I tried cuda in parallel and got 1ms in both cases.

Comment: My problem has been solved when I had to reboot my computer :(